# Calling different methods from different traits in scala with multiple inheritance

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance, traits

Let's take the following example

```
trait Drawable {
  def draw
  def paint
}

trait Cowboy extends Drawable {
  override def draw() { println("Bang!") }
  override def paint(){ println("I need this to be painted")}
}

trait Artist extends Drawable {
  override def draw() { println("A pretty painting") }
  override def paint(){ println("I don't want this to be painted")}
}

class CowboyArtist extends Cowboy with Artist

object Main extends App {
  (new CowboyArtist()).draw() // A pretty painting
  (new CowboyArtist()).paint() // I don't want this to be painted
}
```

Here, `Artist` and `Cowboy` inherit `Drawable` and override the methods `draw` and `paint`. `CowboyArtist` inherits both Cowboy and Artist in the same order. From what I have [read](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/05/30/traits-how-scala-tames-multiple-inheritance/), scala determines which method to be called based on the order in which its inherited and the methods from the right most trait would be executed.

But what if I want one of the method to be called from the one trait which another method from another trait, as you see the example, I want the `draw` method to be executed from `Artist` trait but I want the `paint` method to be executed from the `Cowboy` trait.

Is this possible? If not what is the workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just use:

```
class CowboyArtist extends Cowboy with Artist {
    override def paint = super[Cowboy].paint
}
```

`super[Trait]` allows you to choose exact trait from linearization you want to call.

So now:

```
scala> (new CowboyArtist()).paint()
I need this to be painted

scala> (new CowboyArtist()).draw()
A pretty painting
```

P.S. you can use `super[Trait]` inside traits as well, so you can create a mixin with correct prioritization before mixing it into class:

```
trait CowboyArtistMixin extends Cowboy with Artist{
    override def paint = super[Cowboy].paint
}

class CowboyArtist extends CowboyArtistMixin
```

Comment: This answer is a great example. No pontificating, no lecture, just answer. It's these kinds of answers that give StackExchange the value. I will be quoting this as an ideal answer going forward if anybody asks me for an example answer..